# With NGRX 8 and createAction, how can I use strongly-typed @Effect?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm migrating a large codebase from NGRX 7 to 8.

My actions look like this:

```ts
export class DeleteRecordAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.DELETE_RECORD;
  constructor(public payload: IRecord);
}
export class DeleteRecordSuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS;
}
export class DeleteRecordFailureAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.DELETE_RECORD_FAILURE;
}
```

and my effects look like this (note the strongly-typed return Observable):

```ts
@Effect() deleteRecord$: Observable<DeleteRecordSuccessAction | DeleteRecordFailureAction> =
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Actions.DeleteRecordAction>(ActionTypes.DELETE_RECORD),
    switchMap((action) => this.recordService.deleteRecord(action.payload).pipe(
      map((result) => new Actions.DeleteRecordSuccessAction()),
      catchError((err) => of(new Actions.DeleteRecordFailureAction())),
    )),
  );
```

I'm trying to migrate the actions to use the new createAction syntax, which is easy enough:

```ts
export const DeleteRecordAction = createAction('[FOO] Delete Record', props<{ payload: IRecord }>());
export const DeleteRecordSuccessAction = createAction('[FOO] Delete Record Success');
export const DeleteRecordFailureAction = createAction('[FOO] Delete Record Failure');
```

but now my @Effect won't compile at the following line:

```ts
@Effect() deleteRecord$: Observable<DeleteRecordSuccessAction | DeleteRecordFailureAction> =
```

with the errors:

> TS2749: 'DeleteRecordSuccessAction' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
>   TS2749: 'DeleteRecordFailureAction' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

I can remove the strong-typing from the @Effect return value and just use the generic `Action`, like this:

```ts
@Effect() deleteRecord$: Observable<Action> =
```

but then I lose the useful type-checking of the return values, thereby making the code more error-prone.
The new `createEffect` method doesn't seem to help. Is there a way to use NGRX 8 while retaining strong-typing on effects? Or should I just stick with NGRX 7 syntax?

Comment: Can you show the updated effect?

Comment: I haven't updated the effect. I should be able to use the old @Effect() syntax side-by-side with the new createAction() syntax.

Comment: You must have updated the effect to use the new action creator functions.